# Cloudflare WARP gives SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: curl, openssl, cloudflare-warp

it looks like at the beginning of the 2024 something happened to my warp connection.
i cant make any request on the warp tunnel if i try to use HTTPS protocol.

for example, when i try to make a request to telegram api with Curl on my Ubuntu Server, its something like this:

```
curl -x "socks5://127.0.0.1:40000" -v https://api.telegram.org

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:40000...

* TCP_NODELAY set

* SOCKS5 communication to api.telegram.org:443

* SOCKS5 connect to IPv4 10.10.34.36:443 (locally resolved)

* SOCKS5 request granted.

* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 40000 (#0)

* ALPN, offering h2

* ALPN, offering http/1.1

* successfully set certificate verify locations:

*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):

* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.telegram.org:443

* Closing connection 0

curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.telegram.org:443
```

im using warp-cli on proxy mode (port 40000).